# Regex - I keep getting "Nothing to repeat" exception

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I use this regex code to parse urls:

```
/^(((http|https):\/\/)+[www.])?+\s*\S+\s*+(.com|.es|.net|.org|.co)$/ig
```

It works perfectly on https://regex101.com/r/bX5oM4/1

But on my console I keep getting the:

> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/^(((http|https):\/\/)+[www\.])?+\s*\S+\s*+(\.com|\.es|\.net|\.org|\.co)$/`: Nothing to repeat

I tried escaping the + but It doesn't work. I'm kinda new on regex so It could be anything.

Comment: Which language you're using?

Comment: Javascript, angular-js

Comment: Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/bX5oM4/3)

Comment: Note that it _doesn't work_ on regex101.  If you [set the language to javascript](https://regex101.com/r/lY1lO0/1), you get the error there too: _"Preceding token is not quantifiable"_

Comment: It works!, thank you Tushar. And you're right James Thorpe, thank u too!. How can I close the question or Vote the correct answer?

Comment: I doubt your regex works perfectly, as [it matches `http://googlemcom`](https://regex101.com/r/bX5oM4/4).

Comment: You are right, I hate regex so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your fixed regex:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]\S+(\.(?:com|es|net|org|co))$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX5oM4/14)

Or, to match the strings inside larger strings:

```
\b(?:https?:\/\/www\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9]\S+(?:\.(?:com|es|net|org|co))\b
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/bX5oM4/13)

In JavaScript, you cannot set `+` to `?` quantifier.

Also, note that `[www.]` matches 1 character, either `w` or `.` since it is a character class. You must have meant a group, and thus you need round brackets, not square ones.

I removed unnecessary groups, regrouped them a bit and escaped the dots. Note that unescaped dot matches any character but a newline.

So, the regex:

- `^` - Asserts the position at the start of the string
- `(?:https?:\/\/www\.)?` - Optionally matches `http` or `https` then `//www.` literally
- `\w\S+` - 1 alhoanumeric and 1 or more non-whitespace characters
- `(\.(?:com|es|net|org|co))` - Matches a dot and then any of the alternatives in the round brackets
- `$` - Asserts end of string

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm struggling with that of the newline, I would like to match any url in a string. For instance:
"Hi my name is www.google.com" This would have to match, but it doesn't.

Comment: Then remove the anchors `^` and `$`, use `\b` instead.

Comment: Thank you. I dont know why but someone voted u negative. I marked u as the correct answer, Thanks for ur help. I will try the \b.
 And with the "\s*\S+\s*" thing I was trying to not allow whitespaces. Do you think I should use [^-\s] instead?

Comment: Just remove the `\s*` from the pattern. I updated the patterns.

Comment: You are welcome. Note I have also added `[a-zA-Z0-9]` so as the string you get does not begin with punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (update!)

```
^((http|https):\/\/)?([\w]+[.-]?)+\.(com|es|net|org|co|uk|de)$
```

instead of

```
/^(((http|https):\/\/)+[www.])?+\s*\S+\s*+(.com|.es|.net|.org|.co)$/ig
```

You had an extra `+` behind a `?` and another one behind a `*`. And several other things were not quite OK, as stribizhev pointed out quite rightly!

This regex is looking for a limited range of TLDs ... (e. g. french pages would not pass). The `[www.]` was syntactically wrong and also surperfluous as any domain name can have subdomains (expressed by `([\w]+[.-]?)+`)  and 'www.' is just one of the possible ones.

Comment: This regex [will match `http://googlemcom` and `http://.google.com`](https://regex101.com/r/sK1cL6/1). I do no think this is expected.